# FATAL THREAD PANIC : unknown Torch class <nn.BlockGradient> (user define class)

Tags: lua, torch

i run "allenai/temporal-field"

Why this error occur? 
and why factory of "nn.BlockGradient" is nil?
please help me.
i need your help.

This is BlockGradient.lua Code.
Path is "~/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/nn/BlockGradient.lua"

[BlockGradient.lua Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbqo6.png)

[classname,factory output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5hrU.png)

Comment: Welcome onboard. Please refrain from using images as code snippets

Comment: Because `BlockGradient` is not a class known to Torch :) Seriously, if you want ppl to help you invest some time in preparing a question.

Comment: @minerals what is ppl?  Factory value of BlockGradient Class has something in "requir ('BlockGradient')" declared  lua file, but that has nil value in ~/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua. i don't know why has nil value.